# Activities in Montreal for a Bachelor party

Tags: sightseeing, international-travel, activities, nightlife, montreal

I'm currently planning a bachelor party for a friend, and plan on holding it in Montreal next month. There a some people in our group who have a passing familiarity with the area, but mostly only know the nightclub scene. (Which, if they're correct, is in St. Laurent. I couldn't find anything online to verify.)

So far, my research shows that most of the happening is in downtown Montreal, Mont Royal, and Plateau Mont Royal areas. However, searching for stuff to do repeatedly turns up historical/slow-paced activities in Montreal (e.g., Vieux/Old Montreal, Place de Beaux Arts).

Given this, can anyone provide recommendations for activities? I'm mostly interested in daytime activities, but I'm open to nighttime ones as well. (And if it makes any difference, we're from the US, and know no French.)

Comment: What kind of 'activities' are you interested in?

Comment: As Ankur says, what kind of activities? For example, what about winter sports? (There should be plenty of those still in March).

Comment: I'm looking for something more than mild (e.g., museums/historical sites only), but just short of strip clubs. Skiing sounds like a great idea, though, now that you mention it.

Comment: How about skiing in a museum of strippers?

Comment: @loosebruce As much as I would love to, my friend isn't really into strippers, so no cigar.

Comment: Seriously, the irony of taking someone to Montreal for a Bachelor party who doesn't like strippers is quite frankly amazing.

Comment: @toleero Ouch. That bad?

Comment: @Edwin No.  It's much worse.

Answer (score 5):

As a bachelor party this would probably be....  I am not sure but let me get some stuff out there to see if this will work.

There was nothing much in Quebec from the [Heritage Canada Foundation](http://www.heritagecanada.org/en/visit-discover/find-historic-places) but one was of interest:

[Maison Historique George-Etienne Cartier](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g155032-d183965-Reviews-Maison_Historique_George_Etienne_Cartier-Montreal_Quebec.html)

There is a whole bunch of [festivals](http://www.montreal.com/tourism/festivals/index.html), but I don't know which ones you will be able to make or be interested in.

Later in the year there are a whole bunch of street performers in the Old City but in March it is still too cold.

I am sure that have already seen [the list of main attractions in Montreal](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g155032-Activities-Montreal_Quebec.html).

Of course for the people who live there the biggest one is probably [The Canadiens](http://canadiens.nhl.com/index.html)