# Non-'adult' activities in Austin (USA) for a bachelor party

Tags: activities, austin

I'll be traveling to Austin, TX for a bachelor party. As none of the guys in our group have been to Austin (and I was only there for a couple days 5 years ago), I'm trying to discover some non-adult activities we can do there.

My two biggest challenges are:

1. Bachelor party websites for Austin keep touting 'adult' activities, but the bachelor has zero interest in that.
2. Some of the suggested activities are way too expensive. The guys going aren't poor but $500 for a "party barge" + $200/hr is too much.

Can anyone suggest some non-Adult, Austin specific activities that would be fun for a bachelor party weekend?

Some ideas I've already run across are: tubing (River Sports Tubes) and indoor go-karting (K1 Speed).

Comment: You're going to the wrong place to ask— survey the guests for the party as to what activities they'd like to do. If youre really bereft of ideas, don't search for "bachelor party," which will tend to bring up "adult" activities; search for "guys' weekend" or some such, and you'll turn up all manner of golf outings, pub crawls, racetrack days, paintball, fishing, etc. But, again, we can't possibly guess as to what they might enjoy. Your group might like a quiet night playing poker or video games for all we know.

Comment: Why go with some company to organise a party for you? Why not do it yourself? I'm sure there's a lot to do in Austin that's not "adult oriented". Figure out what your friends like, and find a place where you can do that.

Comment: @Vince: Why is my question off-topic but this [one](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5637/activities-in-montreal-for-a-bachelor-party) isn't?

Comment: The other question is clearly about traveling (the asker is from the US, there is a known "party-tourism" of Americans going to Quebec as the laws on drinking are more tolerant, and it is asked in a manner that suggest the discovery of the city). Your question on the other hand sounds totally like "I am looking for partying", no link with travel. It is not always obvious whether a question is enough related to travel or not. But if you are really traveling for this event, clearly show it in your question. At the top of this page, there is a big "Travel" written, not "Party"!

Comment: @Vince: While I still feel like your concern is pure semantics (and there's really no substantive difference between my question and the other one), I have attempted to reword my question per your suggestion.